# Column Client Template in GRID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am Migrating the app from MVC 5 to Core 2.0. We are facing issue with the grid client template as we are unable to use it when we use it along with the editable property. Following is the code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PPVR>()
    .Name("PPVRGird")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
        columns.Bound("").ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='k-grid-edit custom-action-button'onclick='customGridEditClick(this)'><img src='/Content/edit.svg' width ='40' height='40'/><br/>Edit</a></div>").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-action-button" }).Title("Edit").Width(150);
        columns.Bound("").ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align:center'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='custom-action-button pull-center' onclick='deletePayPerViewRules(#=Id#)'><img src='/Content/trashed.svg' width='40' height='40' /><br />Delete</a></div>").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-action-button" }).Width(200);
        })
        .Pageable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = " text-align:left; font-family:lato; font-size:16px; " })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(100)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetPPVR", "PPV"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(u => u.Id);
            model.Field(u => u.Type).Editable(false);
        })
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdatePPVR", "PPV")))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
)
```

This brings the empty page. When I comment the line **.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))** page appears. It works well in MVC 5 but not in core 2.0.

Kindly suggest how can I achieve this.

**UPDATE** => This issue is coming only when I am using Inline option for editing when I use Pop Up then it works fine.

Comment: For my template only columns I use `columns.Template(t => { }).ClientTemplate...`. Are you getting a console error? Same version of Kendo in both?

Comment: The JavaScript Version is same for DLL I followed the steps as recommended on Kendo Website to add Telerik as a nuget source and then download the packages.

What I do require is to have extra columns with custom buttons.

Comment: UPDATE => This issue is coming only when I am using Inline option for editing when I use Pop Up then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after 2 days of waiting I got the response from Telerik Team.

A possible solution is to bind the desired columns to any field, and using the columns.editable configuration to prevent editing for these columns. 
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editable

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).ClientTemplate("Hi").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-action-button" }).Width(200).Editable("function(){return false;}");
columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).ClientTemplate("Bye").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-action-button" }).Title("Sample").Width(150).Editable("function(){return false;}");
```

[Telerik Team Answer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/client-template-in-grid-f2c4821fb7d8#-FPbUeSThkCIHPy-7rdgxw)

It seems to be a workaround for me but it worked fine.

Hope this question saves someother people time as well.